# Class not found error in REST webservice in Yii2

Tags: web-services, yii2, yii2-web-service

I have these line of codes in FruitController.php file:

```
namespace app\controllers;
use yii\rest\ActiveController;

class FruitController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'app\models\Fruit.php';
}
```

When I call the page : http://localhost/fruits this fatal error is given:

```
<response>
   <name>PHP Fatal Error</name>
   <message>Class 'app\models\Fruit.php' not found</message>
   <code>1</code>
   <type>yii\base\ErrorException</type>
   <file>/var/www/html/webservices/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/rest/IndexAction.php</file>
   <line>114</line>
   <stack-trace>
      <item>#0 [internal function]: yii\base\ErrorHandler->handleFatalError()</item>
      <item>#1 {main}</item>
   </stack-trace>
</response>
```

Model file exists in models directory and some content like these lines:

```
 namespace app\models;
 use Yii;

 class Fruit extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
 {
    .....
 }
```

I am confused. what is the problem?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Class name is `app\models\Fruit` (without `.php`).

Comment: @rob006 Yessssss!!! It should be without extension. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Class name should be without (.php)

```
namespace app\controllers;
use yii\rest\ActiveController;

class FruitController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'app\models\Fruit';
}
```